# prove $\Bbb{Z}_2[x] /(x^3+x+1)$ is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Prove that $$\Bbb{Z}_2[x] /(x^3+x+1)$$ is a field.

---

Attempt 1

$\Bbb{Z}_2 $ is a field , $p(x)=x^3+x+1$ is a non constant polynomial in $\Bbb{Z}_2[x]$

$(x^3+x+1)$ is irreducible in $\Bbb{Z}_2[x]$ then $\Bbb{Z}_2[x]/\big(p(x)\big)$ is a field.

*it has been a while since taking ring theory appreciate corrections and/or ciriticism*

Comment: It is true that showing that $p(x)$ is irreducible will suffice to show that you have a field. If it's not irreducible, then it factors as a product of a linear and a quadratic (or as a product of three linear polynomials). You should check to see if it has a linear factor. The good news is that there are not very many linear factors to check, as there are only $2$ elements in the base field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to show this. Theoretically, $x^3+x+1$ is irreducible, and so it is a maximal ideal in $k[x]$ so the quotient is a field. This is probably the quickest way. To show that it is irreducible, note that if $x^3+x+1$ were reducible, it would factor into the product of three linear components or one linear and one quadratic.

Thus, one only needs to show that  roots of $x^3+x+1 $ are not in $\mathbb Z_2$. In particular, if $x^3+x+1=0$, then $x^3+x=1$, so, but this is impossible, since $x=0,1$ both give $0$ as solutions.